Change in two spectral deviations due to edge deletion in a signed graph
Prove (or disprove) the following. Let $\Sigma=(G,\sigma)$ be a given signed graph. If $\lambda_1\ge\lambda_2\ge\cdots\ge \lambda_n$ and  $\mu_1\ge\mu_2\ge\cdots \ge \mu_n$ are the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrices of $\Sigma$ and $G$, respectively, and if $\beta_A(\Sigma) =\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\lambda_i-\mu_i)^2$, then $\beta_A(\Sigma-e)\le \beta_A(\Sigma)$. Here $e$ may be either a positive edge or a negative edge. Note that the underlying graph of $\Sigma-e$ is $G-e$ for which the corresponding adjacency eigenvalues may be taken as $\lambda'_1\ge\lambda'_2\ge\cdots \ge \lambda'_{n}$ and  $\mu'_1\ge\mu'_2\ge\cdots \ge \mu'_{n}$, respectively.

We have proved that for any signed graph $\Sigma$ with $n$ vertices $0\le\beta_A(\Sigma)\le2n(n-2)$. The lower limit is attained by all balanced signed graphs and the upper limit is satisfied by all-negative signed complete graphs of order $n$.

To correct the mathematical typose above. Moreover, while expanding both $\beta_A(\Sigma)$ and $\beta_A(\Sigma- e)$, we can use the facts $\sum\limits_{i=i}^{n}\lambda_i^2=2m=\sum\limits_{i=i}^{n}\mu_i^2$, $\sum\limits_{i=i}^{n}\lambda_i'^2=2m-2=\sum\limits_{i=i}^{n}\mu_i'^2$ where $m$ denotes the number of edges in $G$. So that  $\beta_A(\Sigma)-\beta_A(\Sigma-e)=4+2(\sum\limits_{i=i}^{n}\lambda'_i\mu'i-\sum\limits{i=i}^{n}\lambda_i\mu_i)$.

Again we have the following two facts. 1) $n\le \sum\limits_{i=i}^{n}\lambda_i\mu_i\le 2m$ and $n\le \sum\limits_{i=i}^{n}\lambda'_i\mu'_i\le 2m-2$

Also fact 2) $1\le \lambda_1\le n-1$ and $1\le \lambda'_1\le n-1$
